# write hive table create schema by fetching table schema from sql sever

Tags: sql-server, hive, rdbms

I have tables in `SQL Server` which needs to cloned as `hive` tables. Since the create table schema will be different in both the cases,

I simply cannot use the create table statement from `SQL Server` or from any other `RDBMS` in `hive`.

I am trying to create a configurable script where one can provide the table schema as an input and it would provide me `hive` create table statements or a hql file with the create table schema

has anyone tried something similar.

Comment: Use Sqoop, it automatically creates hive schema using command create-hive-table.

Comment: I don't want  to use sqoop here . I am looking out for a solution apart from sqoop as I need to move the data to azure